# concatenating string with variable in erlang

Tags: string, erlang, string-concatenation

I have below string in erlang which I get from `Msg#archive_message.body`

```
{\"message\":\"tttfdfdfdfdddtt\",\"customid\":\"454dddfdfdfd\"}
```

I need to make it

```
  <<"{\"message\":\"tttfdfdfdfdddtt\",\"customid\":\"454dddfdfdfd\"}">>
```

and pass into a function. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

> {\"message\":\"tttfdfdfdfdddtt\",\"customid\":\"454dddfdfdfd\"}

is a string you just need to convert it to binary with erlang:list_to_binary/1

Comment: P_A ... thanks it works... how to convert it to normal string when we have `<<"ererereer">>`

Answer (score 1):

```
Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)
1> unicode:characters_to_binary("{\"message\":\"tttfdfdfdfdddtt\",\"customid\":\"454dddfdfdfd\"}").
<<"{\"message\":\"tttfdfdfdfdddtt\",\"customid\":\"454dddfdfdfd\"}">>
```

Then you can use [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx) to parse it into a list

```
2> jsx:decode(<<"{\"message\":\"tttfdfdfdfdddtt\",\"customid\":\"454dddfdfdfd\"}">>).
[{<<"message">>,<<"tttfdfdfdfdddtt">>},
 {<<"customid">>,<<"454dddfdfdfd">>}]
```

Or into a map

```
3> jsx:decode(<<"{\"message\":\"tttfdfdfdfdddtt\",\"customid\":\"454dddfdfdfd\"}">>, [return_maps]).
#{<<"customid">> => <<"454dddfdfdfd">>,
  <<"message">> => <<"tttfdfdfdfdddtt">>}
```

Comment: NO, why should we use a additional library when its possible with core functions.

Comment: `list_to_binary/1` can take only up to 0..255. For example `list_to_binary([322])` would crash.